# Finding out who dmed the bot. | Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've tried this code:

```
        footer: {
          text: `${message.author.user}`
        },
```

It's in embed by the way. How can you figure out who dmed the bot?

Comment: ${message.author.user} can be changed to ${message.author}, after that you can go off of [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.5.1/class/User) to get the property you want. Also next time you should probably put in more code & information.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm kind of new of this website and in programming. I'm sorry if I did not add more information. I'll try to add more information next time I ask another question.